# Obtengo un 403 en Python en una web pública

Tags: python, http, cabeceras-http, error-403

Estoy haciendo un programa en Python para hacer una descarga de un archivo.
Manualmente le doy click derecho a un .gif y me abre un dialogo para guardarlo, pero  como archivo .webp
El formato del enlace es algo así como 'https://cdn.urlfalsa.com/images/anim/2023/02/22/12345678.gif?width=300'
He intentado hacer lo que se supone que hace el navegador:
HTTP GET y luego leer la respuesta para ver tipo de archivo y nombre, pero siempre obtengo un 403.
Como no creo que sea un problema de autenticación, porque la web no lo necesita, he tratado de hacer varias cosas:
Enviar una cabecera en diversos formatos de menor a mayor hasta llegar a :

```
cabecera = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
}
```

El GET lo he hecho de diversas formas: requests.get y con requests.session
Tambien he utilizado Request de urrlib.request
Me surge la duda de si en una de las muchas pruebas que he hecho se me haya pasado la combinación ganadora :)
¿Porque no puedo automatizar con Python lo que hago con el navegador de forma manual?

Comment: Revisa la URL, ya que la dirección no existe: *We can’t connect to the server at cdn.urlfalsa.com*

Comment: Normalmente, a los CDN se accede desde una web que es la _"referente_" de la petición HTTP. Tu cliente HTTP debe imitar el uso que hace la web, por lo que hay que investigar más cómo lo hace. Sólo con el formato del enlace no es posible saber más.

Comment: Siento no haber pegado un enlace real. No quise violar algun tipo de politica de la web. Tengo una aplicación de descargas de proposito general y aunque me ha pasado en varias ocasiones, la última ha sido con esta animación https://cdn.sex.com/images/pinporn/2023/02/03/28835030.gif?width=300

Comment: Usando un navegador web ingresas normalmente, es decir, desde el Chrome o edge o el que utilices no tiene problema al ingresar?

Comment: No, no tengo ningún problema. Prueba el enlace real que he puesto mas arriba. Ves perfectamente el gif y con click derecho le das a descargar y lo hace perfectamente.

Comment: Probe el "enlace real" y me da una página "403 Forbidden". Debe faltar el "referente", como dice @ChemaCortes. Si el sitio no ve un referente "legitimo", interpreta que es un bot tratando de recolectar imagenes y videos, y lo bloquea.

Comment: Más que el enlace real, lo importante es el contexto de la web original que lo usa. A veces, los CDN se protegen con _hashes_, en la url o en las cabeceras, que controlan cosas como la caducidad o la disponibilidad geográfica del contenido. Mejor que acceder directamente a los CDN, intenta automatizar la web que los emplea. Te aconsejo [playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/): https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-download

Comment: Muy interesante lo de playwright, no lo conocía. De momento me da errores por todas partes, pero son de sintaxis.. Aun asi, tiene buena pinta para lo que necesito